# Error number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I realize this error is touched on in other posts, but I still can't figure out how it applies to my particular situation.  I have the following code.

```
myfun <- function(x, g, o){
  y <- x

  fs <- ((g-1)/o) * (o*g/((g-1)*(1+o)))^g
  xb <- o/(g-1)

  y[x>=xb] <- ((x+o)/(1+o))^g
  y[x<xb] <- x*fs

  return(y)
}

x <- seq(0,1,length=5)
y <- myfun(x, 1.5, 0.05)
```

My code is returning the following errors.

```
Warning messages:
1: In y[y >= xb] <- ((x + o)/(1 + o))^g :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In y[y < xb] <- x * fs :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

In addition the results seem to be incorrect.

I expect

```
y = 
    0 0.152720709664243 0.379105500429200 0.665044998814453 1
```

but get :

```
y = 
    [1] 0.00000000 0.01039133 0.15272071 0.37910550 0.66504500
```

This leads me to believe I'm doing something incorrect in my indexing, or there's something going on with the math on the vector x.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction, `x` is of length 5, such that `y` and `((x+o)/(1+o))^g` are of length 5 as well.

However, the test `x>=xb` is only true for 4 elements out of 5, such that `y[x>=xb]` is 4 elements long. Therefore your assignement `y[x>=xb] <- ((x+o)/(1+o))^g` clashes because the two elements are not of the same length.

I guess what you want to do is something like

```
y[x>=xb] <- ((x[x>=xb]+o)/(1+o))^g
y[x<xb] <- x[x<xb]*fs
```

I get

```
>y
[1] 0.0000000 0.1527207 0.3791055 0.6650450 1.0000000
```

which is close from what you want, I'll let you figure that out.

Comment: Thank you ... this is correct.  I figured it out myself just as your answer popped up but I appreciate the confirmation and full description why.

Comment: Another option is to use ifelse function.